# Calling class/instance method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started putting together an app thats a skills matrix for employees.

Each employee has 3 ratings. One from themselves, one from their manager, and one from an expert in the skill.

I want to have each employee have a weighted score based upon the above 3 scores with respective weights (40%, 20%, 40%).

I assume I need to create some sort of method in my model something like:

```
def self.calc_weight
  a = Rating.find(params[:id])
  b = a.emp_score *.4
  c = a.mgr_score *.2
  d = a.sme_score *.4
  e = b + c + d
  a.wgt_score = e
end
```

I know this is improper syntax. Is this the correct approach or should this be something thats handled by my controller after creation of rating? If so on which controller action would i define this? If I'm to utilize a method, I have the same question. I'm sure theres also a better way to do this.

Comment: You wouldn't want a class method calling `params`. If you want this in the model then you'd need to pass in the `rating_id`. Whether or not it *belongs* in the model depends, but there's no reason it can't start off as a model instance method, potentially in a callback (here there be potential dragons). If whatever the model is already *has* a rating relation then you don't need to pass in the rating id, you already have it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have some relations on your models like

```rb
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rating
end
```

If so you just need to add method to Employee model, like:

```rb
def weight
  (rating.emp_score * 0.4 +
    rating.mgr_score * 0.2 +
    rating.sme_score * 0.4).to_i # for integer value
end
```

And call it like `@employee.weight`

**Or**

If you want to add attribute `wgt_score` to Rating model and update it whenever Rating-object updated - then you have to add `before_save` (for example) callback to Rating model like:

```rb
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  before_save :update_weight
  # ...
  private
  def update_weight      
    self.wgt_score = (emp_score * 0.4 +
                      mgr_score * 0.2 +
                      sme_score * 0.4)
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer. Minor nitpick, I might call the method `weighted_score` or something like that, since that's what its calculating.

Comment: I have an intermediate table so i have a Rating table/model that belongs_to Employee and Skills. Skills just has a skill_id and summary and has many employees through rating . The Rating table has the FKs of both employee and skills and all the ratings stored in it. I assume the approach would be similar. Once i have the method defined where should it be called?

Comment: Since the `weight` method is only using attributes from `rating`, the method as a whole should be moved to the `Rating` class. Then, in the `Employee` class, you can define a delegation to that method: `delegate :weight, to: :rating`. Then you can still call `employee.weight` while the method is actually defined in `Rating`.